# how to add multi animation for one image when create video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I are using ffmpeg to create video from many images.
Example I'm using command below to create 1 video.

```
Sample Command. 
ffmpeg \
  -loop 1 -t 5 -i img001.jpeg \
  -loop 1 -t 5 -i img002.jpeg \
  -loop 1 -t 5 -i img003.jpeg \
  -loop 1 -t 5 -i img004.jpeg \
  -loop 1 -t 5 -i img005.jpeg \
  -filter_complex \
 "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; \
 [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; \
 [2:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2]; \
 [3:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3]; \
 [4:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v4]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

But I'm having a problem. For example, image001.png, I only know add single animation for this image when creating the video.

How do I add multi animation to an image? For example, rotate, move from top to center, then from center to right.

Thankyou very much.

Comment: You can use overlay for some of these effects, but it is not trivial. `ffmpeg` is not a video editor. `melt` may be a better tool for this if you need a command-line editor. Or look into [ffmpeg-gl-transition](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-gl-transition) (I've never used it so I can't comment further on it).

Comment: Thank you for the given. I will try it. @LordNeckbeard

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Suppose I want to do an effect like the video below.
Fadein into the photo, move the photo, and then fadeout the photo.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDL4SlJPak
If you have any information, please guide me.
Thank you very much.